# How to let JavaScript know where I am on the site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single template file which renders pages that look very similar, but behave a bit different. I have a header and a few text boxes, which are filled by the template language, and there is a canvas, whose content actually differentiates the pages. It basically comes down to calling a different JavaScript function based on the page I am on, and I can't really think of an elegant (!) way to do that.

I have a single JavaScript file that uses jQuery's document ready callback to add interactivity to the site, and also to do the drawing in the canvas. For that, I have to call a specific drawing function based on which page I am on, but I don't know it at that point.

This is certainly not impossible, I can in fact think of several different solutions, but don't really like any of these. The script file is not run through a template engine, so I can't employ any server-side logic there. I could parse the URL in the script, but this sounds like a hack to me. I could also set a variable in a script block within the template file, set a hidden field's value or something like that, but I don't think this logic belongs into the template either.

So how is this usually done?

Comment: Could I suggest adding the jQuery tag to your question? (That is, if you're happy to accept jQuery answers, obviously. But you seem to be using it already, so I'm assuming that you're okay with that...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed any JavaScript you want on to a web page, built with the same server-side logic you would build the page with. So you can set global variables or (preferably) invoke functions from your .js files with parameters that contain page-specific logic. Just supply the scripts between `<script>` tags.

Comment: As you can see from my question, I was already aware of this solution but thought there must be something better. Since I didn't like the other suggestions much, I guess I'll just do it this way, setting a global variable on my page...

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `<body>` tag a "class" value, and your JavaScript code can use that (and other similar cues) to know what sorts of behaviors to add.

For example, your code could do something like:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('image-gallery')) {
  // ... initialize image gallery code ...
}

if ($('body').hasClass('shopping-cart-summary')) {
  // ... whatever ...
}
```

Of course it doesn't have to be just the `<body>` tag. Your `<canvas>` could also get a "class" value (and/or "data-foo" attributes) to convey information to your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to find the page you are on, or the location in the DOM of a given page. For the former, use *location.href*, or *location.pathname* to avoid the parsing.

Comment: It's true. The thought of having general .js files that contain big switch-type statements of `if (location.href == "....")` is just too horrible to contemplate :-)

Comment: This would duplicate logic I have in my servlet, i.e. which URL leads to which page, on the client, and I don't really like that.